# WPF Flip Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, flip

I'm trying to create a control in WPF, similar to a card, that will have bound data on both "sides".  Using the following code I can get it to flip from FIRST NAME to LAST NAME, just not back.  Once it flips to LAST NAME and I click it just flashes like it's performing the same animation and not running the reverse.  Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.TileControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<UserControl.Resources>
  <Storyboard x:Key="FlipFirst">
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
  <Storyboard x:Key="FlipLast">
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="Front">
     <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard_Begin" Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipFirst}"/>
  </EventTrigger>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="Back">
     <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard_Begin" />
     <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard_Reversed" Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipLast}" />
  </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="280" Height="680">
  <Grid x:Name="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="680" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
     <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
           <ScaleTransform/>
           <SkewTransform/>
           <RotateTransform/>
           <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
     </Grid.RenderTransform>
     <TextBlock x:Name="LastName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Text="LAST NAME" Width="100" Height="100"/>
  </Grid>
  <Grid x:Name="Front" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="680" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
     <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
           <ScaleTransform/>
           <SkewTransform/>
           <RotateTransform/>
           <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
     </Grid.RenderTransform>
     <TextBlock x:Name="FirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="FIRST NAME" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: [Josh Smith already did this for you. Check it out](http://thriple.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I tried something a little bit like this and I could be wrong, but I seem to remember that I had to add a `StopStoryboard` to stop the second `Storyboard`, your `Storyboard_Reversed`... somehow it was interfering with the other one.

Comment: @HighCore The problem with Thriple is that it only works when your control is square.  My control is 280 X 680 which skews the content.  My attempts to play with Thriple and the PerspectiveCamera did not turn out pretty.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is that first time when animation is run, the grid named "back" becomes visible to the user and grid named "front" becomes transparent. But still it is on the top of "Back" grid and capturing all the mouse hit.
So, when user again left click the mouse, it is captured by front grid not the back grid.
To solve this problem, You need to IsHitTestVisible to false when grid is transparent.
See the below code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.TileControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FlipFirst">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FlipLast">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="Front">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard_Begin" Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipFirst}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="Back">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard_Begin" />
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard_Reversed" Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipLast}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="280" Height="680">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="680" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock x:Name="LastName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Text="LAST NAME" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Front" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="680" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock x:Name="FirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="FIRST NAME" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```